# Cannot console.log() textContent from a selected Option Element that was created using a FOR loop in Javascript to populate a list in a Select Element

Tags: javascript, json, for-loop, get, createelement

I have a function that populates a list of option elements into a select element.

```
function createOptionElements(){
    const select = document.querySelector('select');
    for(let i=1;i<11;i++){
        const option = document.createElement('option');
        option.textContent = i;
        select.appendChild(option);
    }
}
```

When I select the option value 3 from the select I would like console.log(option.textContent) to output true.

```
function outputOptionTextContent(){
  const option = document.querySelector('option');
  if (option.textContent === "3"){
    console.log(true);
  }
  else {
    console.log(false);
  }
}
```

When I simply call console.log(option.textContent) I only ever get the first value in the list, which is 1, even If I select a different value.

The reason I am attempting to do this is, I am calling an HTTP GET request on JSON data, the data has name properties, the name properties will be added to the select as options, & I would like to to call a function when a specific name is clicked, so I was thinking of adding a function that looked for the value of textContent and then compared the textContent value to the name in the JSON data, if they match, invoke the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason behind could be the fact that textContent is not an standard attribute the standard attribute is value also is better if you use the method built in to do it

`option.setAttribute(“value”, variableWithValue);`

And yes you guessed it correctly if there is a setAttribute there is also a `getAttribute`

`option.getAttribute(“value”);`

So the end result should look like this

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    console.log('DOM fully loaded and parsed');

   const select = document.querySelector('select');
   for(let i=1;i<11;i++){
     const option = document.createElement('option');
     option.setAttribute(“value”,i);
     select.appendChild(option);
    }

/// add the select to the document
document.body.appendChild(select);

select.addEventListener("change", (e) => {

  const optionSelected = e.target.value;
})

});
```

Comment: So, I found no need for the get/setAttr methods, instead I can just use the e.target.value to invoke a comparison seeing as it stores the value selected by the user.

Comment: If accessibility matters I recommend you to use the attribute value, but I’m glad it helps. Subscribe, share and don’t forget to hit the like button

Answer (score 0):

`document.querySelector` only selects the first element if finds. Instead do `document.querySelectorAll('option')` and it will return a NodeList. With that you can iterate over it and do what you want

---

edit: ignore above

Add an event listener to your select element for input.

```js
select.addEventListener('input', e => {
   let value = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
   console.log(value);
})
```

Comment: typo in the question, question updated, therefore no change in output.

Comment: @lonenigma got it. I just updated my response. Hopefully it works

Comment: unfortunately this solution does not actually solve the problem, even though I can iterate through the nodeList and console.log the specific value from the list, the output needs to log when the user on the front end selects the option, then console.log should display what option was selected.

Comment: Add an event listener when you make the elements
ex: `document.querySelector('select').addEventListener('input', console.log)`

Comment: @lonenigma does this work now? It should. I edited my answer

Comment: I added an event listener that stores e.target.value to invoke a comparison, next would be to test with the JSON data and the stored e.target.value